# Why does $E=\{r \in \mathbb{Q} : -2 \leq r \leq 2\}$ have no maximal or minimal?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

In class I was given this example, $E=\{r \in 
\mathbb{Q}  : -2 \leq r \leq 2\}$ ,  as a counter example for the proposition that

> If max E exists for $E \ ordered \subset S$, then Sup E exists and Max
>   E = Sup E.

The proof was something like this:

$ Let \ B_0 \in \ E, \ then \ \frac{B_0 +2}{2} \geq B_0 \ and \frac{B_0 +2}{2} \ \in E \ so \ B_0 \ is \ not \ an \ upper \ bound \ and \ is \ not \ max.$

But later my professor said that there was a suprema and infima with Sup E = 2 and Inf E = -2. I'm honestly really confused and I would appreciate it if someone could help me out. I don't understand where the fraction $\frac{B_0 +2}{2}$ came from or how we somehow inferred that the suprema is 2 and the infima is -2.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{B_0 + 2}{2}$ is the midpoint between $B_0$ and $2$, and is rational if $B_0$ is rational.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the hint. I did a little sanity check of my own and I plugged in random numbers like 1.999 as my ${B_0}$ for $\frac{B_0+2}{2}$, and I can see why $\frac{B_0+2}{2} \geq B_0$. But how does one intuitively come up with $\frac{B_0+2}{2}$ to prove that there is no maximum?

Comment: For any $B_0 \in E$ you find another element of $E$ (which happens to be $\frac{B_0 + 2}{2}$) which is $\gt B_0$. This means $B_0$ can not be $\max E$. Since this holds true for $\forall B_0 \in E$ it follows that $E$ does not have a $\max$ element. As far as intuition, this amounts to "halving the distance": if you step from $B_0$ to $2$ the midpoint $\frac{B_0 + 2}{2}$ will be closer to $2$ than $B_0$ is.

Comment: I'm confused too.  The set $E$ that you give does have a maximum element, $2$, and a minimum element $-2$.  And a maximum element, if it exists, is always a supremum.  The proof looks like it's dealing with a different set, $\{ r \in \mathbb{Q} | -2 < r < 2\}$.  Is it possible there's a typo?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thank you for pointing out the obvious ;-) I'll leave my previous comments in, but with the note that they both apply to the case $-2 \lt r \lt 2$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are saying.  The set $\{r\in Q| -2\le r\le 2\}$ certainly **does** have both max and min.  The inf= min is -2 and the sup= max is 2.  I wonder if you do not something like $\{r\in Q| -2\le r^2\le 2\}$ (although the "-2" would be peculiar since a square is never negative)  It is true that there is no rational r such that $r^2= 2$ so the set $\{r\in Q| 0\le r^2\le 2\}$ has no max or min.

Comment: No.  r= -1.4, for example, has $r^2= 19.6$ which is larger than -1 and less than 2 so negative numbers are in that set.